# create a webpage below, to store (set)， get and remove data:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a web page that passes data using jQuery .data(), in one of these buttons I want it to store and then display "Todays date is *todays date and time*" I'm struggling to store and display the date and time when the user clicks the set info to today's date is. I know that you need JavaScript to display date and time but when I added in then this makes the whole code not work. Any suggestions??

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>data demo</title>
  <style>
     div {
     margin: 5px;
     background: yellow;
     }
     button {
     margin: 5px;
     font-size: 14px;
     }
     p {
     margin: 5px;
     color: blue;
     }
     span {
     color: red;
     }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

```
  <div>A div</div>

  <button>Get "info" from the div</button>

  <button>Set "info" to "hello,welcome to Question 4"</button>

  <button>Set "info" to today's date</button>// the button to display date and time


  <button>Remove "info" from the div</button>

  <p>The "info" value of this div is <span>?</span></p>
  <script>
     $( "button" ).click(function() {
       var value;

       switch ( $( "button" ).index( this ) ) {
         case 0 :
           value = $( "div" ).data( "info" );
           break;
         case 1 :
           $( "div" ).data( "info", "Hello,welcome to Question 4" );
           value = "Stored";
           break;
         case 2 :
           $( "div" ).data( "info", "Today date is " );// to display date and time
          var today = new Date();
     var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
     var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
     var CurrentDateTime = date+' '+time;// to display date and time

           value = "Stored";
           break;
         case 3 :
           $( "div" ).removeData( "info" );
           value = "Removed!";
           break;
       }

       $( "span" ).text( "" + value );
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: *"makes the whole code not work"* is not a proper problem description. What does or doesn't happen? What errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: Seems like OP might be new to JS @charlietfl. To view errors in browser console, press f12 and at the top of that new box navigate to console and read what it says there.

Answer (score 0):

In your `switch case` for index 2 you need to concatenation with your date. Your code should be like this

```
$("div").data("info", 'Today date is '+CurrentDateTime);
```

**DEMO**

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var value;

  switch ($("button").index(this)) {
    case 0:
      value = $("div").data("info");
      break;
    case 1:
      $("div").data("info", "Hello,welcome to Question 4");
      value = "Stored";
      break;
    case 2:

      var today = new Date();
      var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
      var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
      var CurrentDateTime = date + ' ' + time; // to display date and time
      $("div").data("info", 'Today date is '+CurrentDateTime); // to display date and time
      value = "Stored";
      break;
    case 3:
      $("div").removeData("info");
      value = "Removed!";
      break;
  }

  $("span").text("" + value);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  color: blue;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>A div</div>
<button>Get "info" from the div</button>
<button>Set "info" to "hello,welcome to Question 4"</button>
<button>Set "info" to today's date</button>
<button>Remove "info" from the div</button>
<p>The "info" value of this div is <span>?</span></p>
```